# Histograms in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, histogram, bins

Relatively new to python and pandas. I have a dataframe: `df` with say 2 columns (say, `0` and `1`) and n rows. I'd like to plot the histograms of the two time series data represented in the two columns. I also need access to the exact counts in the histogram for each bin for later manipulations.

```
b_counts, b_bins = np.histogram(df[0], bins = 10)
a_counts, a_bins = np.histogram(df[1], bins = 10)

plt.bar(b_bins, b_counts)
plt.pbar(a_bins, a_counts)
```

However I get an error for incompatible sizes, i.e, length of the bins array is 11 whereas the length of counts array is 10. Two questions:
1) Why does the histogram in numpy an extra bin? i.e., 11 instead of 10 bins
2) Assuming question 1) above can be solved, is this the best/simplest way of going about this?

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?  You're calling functions from `np` and `plt` but it's not clear what they are or what your input data looks like.

Answer (score 2):

I would directly use Pyplot's built in [histogram](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html) function:

```
b_counts, b_bins, _ = plt.hist(df[0], bins = 10)
a_counts, a_bins, _ = plt.hist(df[1], bins = 10)
```

---

As per the documentation of [numpy.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) (if you scroll down far enough to read the `Returns` section in parameter definition):

> **hist** : *array* The values of the histogram. See density and weights for
>   a description of the possible semantics.
>
> **bin_edges** : *array of dtype
>   float* Return the bin edges `(length(hist)+1)`.

Quite clear, isn't it?